# Can I Skip Filling in Default Values on a Function?

Tags: swift, function

with this example function:

```
func sliderSubAction(
  _ slider: UISlider, 
  _ text: String,
  _ consoleText: String, 
  _ sliderType: SliderType = .basic, 
  _ sliderMultiplier: Float = 100, 
  _ affixConsoleText: String = "") 
{...}
```

As you can see, the last 3 required variables are given default values.  My question is, is there a way to write this:

```
sliderSubAction(slider, "ASDelayFeedback", "feedback", .basic, 100, "%")
```

But without filling in the 4th & 5th variables, since they are just using the default function values?

I arranged my variable in the order of "most likely to not use the default value" to "least likely" already.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note. It’s really bad practice to not have labelled parameters. By removing the labels like that you’re just making it harder to read and understand.

Comment: Also... by having labels you don’t need to worry about the order of the parameters etc... you can skip default parameters by name.

Comment: @Fogmeister Could you write an example of what you mean? or give me a link?  I'm also confused by your sidenote.  2 of the 3 text arguments are indeed being sent to populate a label, the other 1 is being sent to a different piece of software on the backend of the app.  Are you saying it's bad practice to use Strings and not UILabels in these contexts?

Comment: No, your method signature. The underscores. Those are removing the parameter labels. Remove the underscores and tbh... your problem pretty much disappears. You need a VERY good reason to be putting those underscores there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making things hard for yourself by removing the parameter labels in the function signature.

When declaring a function you should be looking to make it make sense for everyone.

A function like...

```
func doSomething(_ value1: String, _ value2: String, _ value3: String)
```

might look like you're helping the developer (they have to type less, right?) but you're just making it harder to understand.

When looking at a function like `doSomething("A", "Hello", "Fogmeister")` there is no context.

You also lose the ability to skip default values.

If you give them labels it makes everything much easier...

```
func doSomething(letterOfAlphabet: String = "A", greeting: String = "Hello", name: String = "Fogmeister")
```

Now when calling this function you can skip any of the parameters because you are labeling each parameter.

```
doSomething(name: "PlateReverb")

doSomething(letterOfAlphabet: "B", greeting: "Salut")
```

You don't need to worry about which parameters are skipped because each parameter is given a label.

Stop fighting the Swift. It is making things hard for yourself.

In your case you can simply remove the underscores.

```
func sliderSubAction(
  slider: UISlider, 
  text: String,
  consoleText: String, 
  sliderType: SliderType = .basic, 
  sliderMultiplier: Float = 100, 
  affixConsoleText: String = "") {}
```

And now you can call it like...

```
sliderSubAction(
    slider: slider,
    text: "ASDelayFeedback",
    consoleText: "feedback",
    sliderMultiplier: 120
)
```

You can see how I didn't include `sliderType` or `affixConsoleText` and the compiler will know what you mean because I didn't make everything anonymous from the outside. I had to label each parameter.

It also makes it easier to read.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!  Are there any "good practice" uses of the underscore in this way that you can think of?

Comment: @PlateReverb I don’t think I have ever used an underscore like this in a function signature. Ever. I honestly can’t think of why you would need one like this. I’m sure there may be reasons to use them but it’s not something I have ever needed or used.

Comment: @PlateReverb there are some ideas here https://dmitripavlutin.com/useful-details-about-underscore-keyword-in-swift/

Comment: @Fogmeister You may not have written any, but you've certainly used *tons* of APIs that omit parameter labels where they don't add value. `Sequence.map(_:)`, `Swift.abs(_:)`, `Swift.print(_:separator:terminator:)`, `Swift.fatalError(_:)`, to name a few.

Comment: @Alexander excellent examples. My brain was fried when I wrote this answer and couldn’t think of any examples but yes, I’ve used all of those before. 